# Fabricjs filter

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

i made the code,but I always get this error  "TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).filter is not a function
at i.applyFilters "

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg', function(img) {
  var oImg = img.set({
    left: 50,
    top: 50
  });
  canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
  canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
}, {
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

function applyFilter(index, filter) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  obj.filters[index] = filter;
  obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}

var f = fabric.Image.filters;

document.getElementById("input").onchange = function() {
  applyFilter(0, new f.Contrast({
    contrast: parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value, 10)
  }));
};
```

```html
<canvas width=600 height=400 id="c"></canvas>
<input id="input" type="range" min="-255" max="255" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

To

```
obj.applyFilters();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Also, the Contrast filter only accepts values between -1 and 1 (see http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.Contrast.html), so change this line:

```
<input id="input" type="range" min="-255" max="255" value="0" />
```

To this:

```
<input id="input" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
```

And then divide the value from the input by 100

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value, 10) / 100
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg', function(img) {
  var oImg = img.set({
    left: 50,
    top: 50
  });
  canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
  canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
}, {
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

function applyFilter(index, filter) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  obj.filters[index] = filter;
  obj.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

var f = fabric.Image.filters;

document.getElementById("input").onchange = function() {
  applyFilter(0, new f.Contrast({
    contrast: parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value, 10) / 100
  }));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.4.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas width=600 height=400 id="c"></canvas>
<input id="input" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer,but this does not work.the image is only changed to one color

Comment: I've edited my answer since the filter values being applied were also out of range. Also for comments like this please use the comments feature rather than posting it as an answer.